# Mirrored Texture Has Seams

Tags: texturing

I downloaded this model of Zero Suit Samus from the modeler's resource:
https://www.models-resource.com/wii_u/supersmashbrosforwiiu/model/11907/

When I bring it into Blender it has a nasty seam.
I've tried edit mode > select all > mesh > clean up > merge by distance, and nothing changed. How do I get rid of the texture seams?

Thank you for your time! [image]

Comment: I don't have this problem with this dae file. Didn't you adjust the normals in your shader nodes?

Comment: I didn’t know that was a thing. How do you adjust normals??

Comment: In your shader nodes is there anything plugged into a shocket, called Normal? Mirrored normal map doesn't work.

Comment: Yes, I have a normal map plugged in. How do I get the normal map to work then??